# Adding functionality to an existing class (using private fields)

Tags: java, reflection, private

I want to add a few methods to an already-existing class. The class's source code (**read-only**) is available to me.

The challenge is that these new methods are dependent on a private field of the already-existing class, so inheritance is not an option.

In my opinion, I have two not so favorable options for achieving my goal. One option is to copy all the source code to a new class and add there my new methods. The other option is to use `Reflection`. Neither are ideal, the first because it is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. The second, because it is contrary to the main idea of OOP - capsulation.

The question: Is there any other way to accomplish my goal, or am I stuck with only these options?

Comment: Reflection can't solve this problem either.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The newly created class can hold an instance of the existing class, and all public methods will be bridged by the newly created class (Like the decorator pattern). The newly added method will use the private fields of the existing class instance via Reflection.

Comment: When the code using the class has the option to use a different class instead, as both approaches imply, why is it important to have the new methods to be added to the old class? Your description implies that you can place the new methods anywhere and let the code use the old class plus the new methods.

Comment: @Holger IMHO, it's a taste and context issue. Both ways are possible. In my opinion, there should only be one point of responsibility for a whole topic. We must pass the instance of the original private fields to the newly created class when we use reflection to get the original private fields, so that the instance is managed by both classes. Although it is entirely possible, I don't like it.

Comment: The only way to have a single point of responsibility is to create the copy of the source code, drop the old one and become the maintainer of both, the old and the new code. The delegating approach still has two different points of responsibility, even if one of them looks like an API covering everything. And with the first (copy) approach, when you don’t stop using the old, read-only code, you even have code duplication, the opposite of “one point of responsibility”.

Answer (score 1):

The class is not flexible enough. This is a defect to its code. So reimplement the class under an other name and describe all this in the javadoc. Then add your functionality, maybe with inheritance.

True this is an ugly situation, living with bad and good class. Maybe you even need to apply the *adapter pattern* changing a good class instance (your copy) back to a bad class (the original).

You might document a *technical debt*, substituting the implementation with that private field.

One should mention that in case of a public getter, one may hijack the private field and use a second field. But that you would have seen. And makes for complicated semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Natively in java, no, this is not possible.

You should check out [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), I believe it has [something similar to what you are looking for](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod).

If you don't want to use an external library, reflection is going to be your best alternative. Below are two utility methods that can help get you started:

```
public static boolean setField(Object target, String fieldName, Object value) {
    try {
        var f = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(target, value);
        return true;
    } catch(IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static Object getField(Object target, String fieldName) {
    try {
        var f = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return f.get(target);
    } catch(IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the Lombok `@ExtensionMethod` is irrelevant, because the extended method has no extra privilege to any of the private or protected field/methods of the original object.